# Select values of one table which are fields of another table

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on SSRS reporting service 2008.
I have two tables:
Table 1:

```
keyId  KeyName  subKeyId  SubKeyName
-----  -------  --------  ----------
1      alpha    1         Sabc
1      alpha    2         Sdef
1      alpha    3         Sghi
2      station  1         SubPen
2      station  2         SubPencil
3      Home     1         SubMat
3      Home     2         SubSheet
3      Home     3         SubPillow
```

I have a table 2 in which i use the vlaues of table 1 as column names :

```
Year  Month  Sabc  Sdef  Sghi  SubPen  SubPencil  SubPillow
----  -----  ----  ----  ----  -----    --------  ---------
2012  April  45     45   56      35     97          78
2012  June   66     78   95      54     89          08
2013  may    34     23   78      73    98           97
```

I want to create a matrix in my report to group by the Key names from table 1, and show the sub key names from table1 with values from table 2 for them.

```
           |  
           |  SubKpiNames    Values   Sparkline
------------------------------------------------
alpha      |  Sabc            76
           |  Sdef            80 
           |  Sghi            45    
Station    |  SubPen          72
           |  SubPencil       45
Home       |  SubPillow       65
           |  SubSheet        75
           |  SubMat          34
```

How can i do this? How can we map the values of one table with fields of other table.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this by nesting the tables but that would be quite messy and I doubt you'd get the required layout. 
I suggest you do this server side and create a data set from the underlying values of each table.